# Bootstrap styles not being applied to Visualforce page as static resource

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap, stylesheets

I'm working on a very simple validation of getting Bootstrap styles applied to a VF page - I have uploaded Bootstrap 3.3.4 as a static resource, have disabled the header and sidebar, and disabled standard stylesheets...**my question is is there some global setting that might be preventing external styles to be applied?** This is in a client org and I've simplified it down so much but still can't get the styles to be rendered correctly. I followed [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/03/twitter-bootstrap-and-visualforce-in-minutes.html), ripping the HTML from the actual Bootstrap page as a test.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>

    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap/css/grid.css')}" />

  </head>
..... content .....
```

But it's being rendered with no styles at all:

[image]

Here's the directory on my local machine (it was uploaded to static resources as a .zip called "bootstrap"), I believe my URLFORs are structured correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you base folder. In your screenshot it's named bootstrap-3.3.4-dist while in your URLFOR it's only bootstrap/.

Not sure if the top folder is part of your zip. If not try to remove bootstrap/ from URLFOR

So it should be either

```
 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'css/bootstrap.min.css')}" />
```

or

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}" />
```

Btw there is an really awsome (yet unofficial) Firefox plugin to tell you what's really be loaded and what's not. It's called JSView

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=2863589

Comment: Classic example of me getting frustrated and convincing myself something inexplicable was happening, when it was just overlooking something so simple! Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. Without JSView I would end up the same every day.